# XPath filter on value

Tags: c#, wpf, xpath, xmldataprovider

I've got a ListBox with an XMLDataProvider that I want to filter on the specific value of a node.

I've tried the following but it returns the full `<ITEMS>` again.

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="ItemDataSource" XPath="./ITEMS[ITEM[./PROPERTY='value']]" Source="data.xml">
</XmlDataProvider>
```

This is the XML file:

```
<ITEMS>
  <ITEM>
    <PROPERTY>value</PROPERTY>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <PROPERTY>other value</PROPERTY>
  </ITEM>
</ITEMS>
```

`./ITEMS/ITEM[./PROPERTY/text()='value']`
works but since it isn't wrapped by `<ITEMS>` it refuses to display the data.

Comment: What output you expect? `ITEMS`, `ITEM`... what exactly? Also note that `./ITEMS/ITEMS[./PROPERTY/text()='value']` won't work as `ITEMS` has no child `ITEMS`... Do you mean `./ITEMS/ITEM[./PROPERTY/text()='value']`?

Comment: Sorry, just saw my mistake there and edited it

Comment: I expect <items> with only the <item> matched my search, or any way to put only those in a ListBox

Comment: Oh...AFAIK you cannot do this with `XPath` as it can only return element with **all** descendants without modifications

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution using `./ITEMS/ITEM[./PROPERTY/text()='value']` I needed to unset the XPath in `ItemsSource`.